# scrapy.Request() not working with response.url

Tags: web-scraping, scrapy

I am building a spider to crawl different tabs in a page.

There are cases where I need to extract an URL to go to the next page:

```
url = i.css('a').attrib['href'] 
yield response.follow(url=url, callback=self.parse_menu)
```

And there are cases where I dont need to go to a different page, but still want to go to the next step in the pipeline (`parse_menu`), so I do something like this:

```
yield response.follow(url=response.url,callback=self.parse_menu)
```

The first scenario works well, but in the second scenario `parse_menu` never gets called.

I think there is something I am missing in how the request and callback work maybe.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure if I understand you well, but I think you are sending the same request twice, so you need to set dont_filter to True.

```
yield response.follow(url=response.url,callback=self.parse_menu,dont_filter=True)
```

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
url = i.css('a::attr(href)').get()
```